# Web Server AngularJs GET 404 not found

Tags: java, angularjs, tomcat, webserver, http-status-code-404

After moving my web project from Tomcat `/` directory to subfolder `/WebApp` I get an error `GET http://localhost:8080/partials/view-worker-apps-used.html 404 (Not Found)`

This is my project structure:

```
 - WebApp
   - partials
     - view-worker-details.html
     - view-worker-apps-used.html
   - js
     - controlers.js
     - services.js
   - index.html
```

1. First I load `http://localhost:8080/WebApp/#/screen2`
   which is view-worker-details.html injected into index.html by `$routeProvider`
2. In loaded view-worker-details.html screen there is

`<div ng-include="/partials/view-worker-apps-used.html"></div>`

I prefer to not put WebApp prefix into path of ng-include.
How I can fix this problem?

Comment: Add `<base href="WebApp">` to the `<head>` section of your index.html.

Comment: Adding <base doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can take one of following approach.

**Approach 1:** If you are sure that your contextpath will not change then use following path in ng-include.

```
<div>
    <div ng-include="/WebApp/#/screen2/partials/view-worker-apps-used.html"> </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** Remove single quote; it's not require so remove it to avoid confusion

**Approach 2:** If you think that your context name may change in future then I will suggest to re verify the location of following files.
a. First try by removing extra single quote 
b. Verify the location of  view-worker-apps-used.html file using following URL

```
/WebApp/#/screen2/partials/view-worker-apps-used.html
```

c. Verify the location of file in which you have added following line of code and make sure that relative path you have used as "partials/view-worker-apps-used.html" is valid.

```
<div>
    <div ng-include="'partials/view-worker-apps-used.html'"> </div>
</div>
```

I hope it may help.